# X Path Grab Table Data (Drupal Feeds)

Tags: xpath, drupal-7

I am struggling to grab the artist and track name data from these tables as they are identical! Does anyone know how I can do this? Another thing is picking up URL data, this doesn't seem to return either. I have got all the rest of the fields, just stuck on these, any help would be gladly received. (The info here: `<td class="r-pad">`)

```
      <tr data-trid="**1350474**" class="ptk-1350474 play-trk">
    <td class="tnum-td">
      <div class="tnum-ppl-cont">
        <div class="tnum">1</div>
        <div class="play-fly"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="com-play" title="Play Track"></a><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="com-pl" title="Cue Track"></a></div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="thumb"><div class="thumb-cont"><img src="http://static.example.com/scripts/image.php/44x44/240148.jpg" /><img src="http://w-static.example.com/img/promo_large.png" class="**promo**" /></div></td>
    <td class="r-pad"><a href="**/track/1350474/track-name**">**TRACK NAME** </a><br /><span class="version">**Original Version** <span class="duration">**(6:40)**</span></span></td>
    <td class="r-pad"><a href="**/artist/17/artist-name**" class="com-artists" data-aid="17">**Artist Name**</a>, **<a href="/artist/14114/artist-name**" class="com-artists" data-aid="14114">**Artist Name 2**</a><br /></td>
    <td class="label-e r-pad"><div class="lab-div ellip"><a href="/label/8831/music-label-name" title="**Music Label Name**">**Music Label<**/a></div></td>
    <td class="genre-e r-pad"><div class="genr-div ellip"><**a href="/genre/13/country-music**" title="Country Music">**Country Music**</a></div></td>
    <td class="rdate r-pad">**2013-11-14**</td>
    <td class="drop">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="com-drop"></a>
      <div class="ttl-drop-menu">
        <div class="com-drop-menu">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="com-close sm"></a>

          <div class="fol-div ellip">follow <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-follow="{aid: 17}" class="follow">test</a></div>

          <div class="fol-div ellip">follow <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-follow="{aid: 14114}" class="follow">test</a></div>

          <div class="fol-div ellip">follow <a href="javascript:void(0)" data-follow="{lid: 8831}" class="follow">test</a></div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td class="buy-stat"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="com-buy" data-cart="{title_id: 250569, track_id: 1350474, bitrate: 1}" title="Add to Cart"><span class="price">**&#x24;2.99**</span></a></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: @Mark Veenstra i agree with your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get the track name by doing the next XPath:

```
//td[@class='r-pad' and contains(a/@href, 'track')]
```

To get the both artists names, do:

```
//td[@class='r-pad']/a[@class='com-artists']
```

To get the price, do:

```
//td[@class='buy-stat'/a[@class='com-buy']/span[@class='price']
```

To get the track ID, do:

```
//tr[contains(@class, 'play-trk')]/@data-trid
```

Comment: Hi thanks very much for your input. The only thing I still cannot grab now is the
Price: <span class="price">&#x24;2.99</span>

Track ID: `code` <tr data-trid="1350474"

URL: `code` <a href="/track/1350474/track-name">

I tried both these for price but no luck: 
`code` .//td[@class='buy-stat']/span[@class='price']
`code` //span[@class='price']

And no idea why the track ID won't appear as it looks quite simple.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Added the XPath for the price. You forgot to add `a` to it, because `span` is a child of `a` in the example.

Comment: Thanks very much. The only thing I cannot get working now is grabbing the ID. So this is the very top level and the Context. Been scratching my head all day with this one.

Comment: Could you be more specific where the `ID` and `Context` could be found?

Comment: Hello there. The context I am using is the very top class which is also the ID number I need: <tr data-trid="1350474". No matter what command I try I cannot get this data, in this case '1350474'. Any help appreciated.